# scala function not taking string input value from csv

Tags: string, scala, csv

I have written a function in scala - **getperiodicssoAccessToken**, which takes 2 string arguments. When the function is called in the code for http header(Name/Value) by passing the string arguments - it works well and returns the expected string token.

`.headers(loginProfileHeadersTRUE.updated("EK-SSO-Access-Token",getperiodicssoAccessToken("""${Skywardstrue}""","Reperf001")))`

However when I feed the first input string from csv file
`.headers(loginProfileHeadersTRUE.updated("EK-SSO-Access-Token",getperiodicssoAccessToken("${csvparam1}","Reperf001")))`  --> the csvparam1 is getting substituted as string itself(**${csvparam1}**) and the function does not work as expected.

I tried the below formats too:
`.headers(loginProfileHeadersTRUE.updated("EK-SSO-Access-Token",getperiodicssoAccessToken(s"$csvparam1","Reperf001")))` -> compilation error  cannot resolve symbol csvparam1

If I substitute the csvparam1 variable without using it in the getperiodicssoAccessToken function, **the value from csv gets picked and substituted very well**:

`.headers(loginProfileHeadersTRUE.updated("EK-SSO-Access-Token","${csvparam1}"))`

Below is the getperiodicssoAccessToken function

`def getperiodicssoAccessToken(username: String, password: String) : String={some code}`

Ideally the value from csv file should be picked up and substituted as string.
Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: getperiodicssoAccessToken(s"$csvparam1","password1") -> cannot resolve symbol csvparam1. Where csvparam1 is column name of csv file

Comment: However when I use the same variable in the this format "${csvparam1}" - it very well picks the values from csv file. It is only when passed as string argument in function, I am facing this issue.

Comment: The form`s"$csvparam1"` assumes that `csvparam1` is a `String` variable. If not then that won't work. If, as you wrote, it _"takes 2 string arguments"_ then you can't feed it a column name where it expects a `String`. In your question you say the form `"${csvparam1}"` doesn't work, but in your comment you say it does. I think you need to post more code. Your question is not clear.

Comment: `.headers(loginProfileHeadersTRUE.updated("EK-SSO-Access-Token",getperiodicssoAccessToken("$csvparam1","Reperf001")))`  --> the ${csvparam1} is taken as string itself and the function does not work as expected. The getperiodicssoAccessToken function is something like this `def getperiodicssoAccessToken(username: String, password: String) : String={some code}`

Comment: Edit the question to add more code. It's not good in the comments. Please demonstrate where/how `"${csvparam1}"` _"very well picks the values from csv file."_

Comment: If I pass something like(just for the purpose to check if the data from csv file is picked up or not, though my header value is incorrect) `.headers(loginProfileHeadersTRUE.updated("EK-SSO-Access-Token","${csvparam1}"))` In this case the value from csv is substituted in the place of csvparam1